# Tzeddaka when traveling after maariv

Tags: halacha, time, tzedakah-charity, travel

It is recommended to give tzeddakah when embarking on travel, preferably in the morning because of the spiritual 'climate' of day.

“One should not give [tzedakah] before the evening prayers [in contrast to the practice] in the morning.(ibid., Tefillas Arvis, Drush 1) from http://www.chabad.org/therebbe/letters/default_cdo/aid/2281756/jewish/Letter-No-238-Giving-tzedakah-at-night.htm

When should one give tzeddaka for travel if travel starts at night, when it is a new halachic day (say 10pm) - in the morning or afternoon of the previous day or the morning after the night of travel?

Comment: What is your source not to give in the afternoon?

Comment: Thanks for asking: I rechecked and I misread: “The time of the afternoon prayers is a time [when the attributes of] judgment [are expressed]. Hence [tzedakah] is not as necessary” (ibid., Tefillas Minchah, Drush 2). However, “One should not give [tzedakah] before the evening prayers [in contrast to the practice] in the morning.(ibid., Tefillas Arvis, Drush 1) http://www.chabad.org/therebbe/letters/default_cdo/aid/2281756/jewish/Letter-No-238-Giving-tzedakah-at-night.htm

Comment: @Daniel, your question would be much improved if you'd cohesively [edit] into it your source for claiming one shouldn't give _tz'daka_ at night.

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/289769/jewish/Traveling-at-Night.htm